# couldn't find file 'best_in_place.purr'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, best-in-place

I am using the [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem and according to the instructions, in order to implement the elegant error handling using jquery.purr, all I have to do is add this to my `application.js`:

```
//= require best_in_place.purr
```

I did that, but I keep getting this error (after having restarted the server multiple times):

```
couldn't find file 'best_in_place.purr'
  (in myapp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:19)
```

This is what my `application.js` looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.purr
//= require_tree .
```

Thoughts?

For what it's worth, I had best_in_place working before trying to add `.purr`. So I even removed it from my Gemfile, ran `bundle` then put it back and re-ran `bundle` - but still no dice.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not used best_in_place or "purr" - not sure what purr is.

Comment: @Zabba https://code.google.com/p/jquery-purr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[harleyttd](https://github.com/harleyttd) has answered on the [Github repo](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/189#issuecomment-9290775).

He said:

> i think it's because you use the gem release version (via gem
>   'best_in_place') which doesnt include best_in_place.purr yet. try gem
>   'best_in_place', github: 'bernat/best_in_place' instead.
>
> another way is to copy best_in_place.purr from the repo over to a
>   best_in_place.custom in your app and customize it to your own needs.
>   it will allow you to easily debug if things aren't showing up as
>   expected as well

Which actually worked for me.